# Calculate next due date based on start date frequency and current date

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models, plotly-dash

I apologize if this has already been asked...I saw something for excel but I'm trying to do this in python. I have the following model:

```
Class AccountDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    frequency_choices = [
        ('weekly', 'Weekly'),
        ('bi-weekly', 'Bi-Weekly'),
        ('twice-monthly', 'Twice Monthly'),
        ('monthly', 'Monthly'),
        ('yearly', 'Yearly')
    ]
    frequency = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=frequency_choices,
        default="weekly",
    )
```

I'm creating a plotly-dash datatable using pandas and I need to create a column titled "next_due_date". I want the value to be the next due date based on a start date, the current date, and a frequency.

```
Example:
due_date: 12/22/2017
frequency: Bi-Weekly
current date: 11/27/2019
next_due_date should be: 12/6/2019
```

I'm pretty stuck on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you looked at `pd.timedelta`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html

Comment: You could use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html to do what you want i believe